# Mongoose nested populate TypeError

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So i am trying to add comments to my posts for which i used nested populate for mongoose. but as soon as i used nested populate it is giving me error of "posts is not iterable", earlier it was working fine when i had pre populate only users data. I am sharing my code hoping it would explain my concern clearer.

**Error**

```
TypeError: /home/vivek/Vivek/CN WEBD/codel/views/home.ejs:16
    14|     <div id="posts-list-container">
    15|         <ul>
 >> 16|             <% for (post of posts){ %>
    17|                 
    18|                 
    19|             <li>

posts is not iterable
    at eval (eval at compile (/home/vivek/Vivek/CN WEBD/codel/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:662:12), <anonymous>:21:21)
    at home (/home/vivek/Vivek/CN WEBD/codel/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:692:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/home/vivek/Vivek/CN WEBD/codel/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/vivek/Vivek/CN WEBD/codel/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (/home/vivek/Vivek/CN WEBD/codel/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/home/vivek/Vivek/CN WEBD/codel/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/home/vivek/Vivek/CN WEBD/codel/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/vivek/Vivek/CN WEBD/codel/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/vivek/Vivek/CN WEBD/codel/node_modules/express-ejs-layouts/lib/express-layouts.js:77:18)
    at /home/vivek/Vivek/CN WEBD/codel/controllers/home_controllers.js:24:24
    at immediate (/home/vivek/Vivek/CN WEBD/codel/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:5074:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

**Home_controller.js:**

```
const Post = require('../models/post');

module.exports.home = function(req, res){

    Post.find({})
    .populate('user').
    populate({
            path: 'comments',
            populate: {
                path: 'user'
            }
        })
        .exec(function(err, posts){
            return res.render('home', {
            title: "Home",
            posts: posts
        });
    })

};
```

**Home.ejs:** *where i am trying to fetch the data*

```
   <div id="posts-list-container">
        <ul>
            <% for (post of posts ){ %>
                
                
            <li>
                <p><%= post.user.name %>
                <%= post.content %>
                </p>
                <div class="post-comments">
                    <% if (locals.user){ %> 
                        <form action="/comments/create" method="POST">
                            <input type="text" name="content" placeholder="type here to comment">
                            <input type="hidden" name="post" value="<%= post._id%>">
                            <input type="submit" value="Add comment">
                        </form>    
                    <%}%>

                    <div class="post-comment-list">
                        <ul id="post-comments-<%= post._id %>">
                                <% for (comment of posts.comments){ %>
                                    <p>
                                        <%= comment.content %>
                                        <br>
                                        <small>
                                            <%= comment.user.name %>
                                        </small>
                                    </p>
                                <%} %>
                        </ul>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </li>    
            
            <% }%>


        </ul>

    </div>
```

**CommentsSchema model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const commentScehma = new mongoose.Schema({
    content:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    //comment belogns to user
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    post: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post'
    }
},{
    timestamps: true
})

const Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', commentScehma)
module.exports = Comment;
```

**Post Schema Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    // inclue the array of id's of all comments in this post schema itself
    comments: [
        {
           type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: 'comment'  
        }
    ]


},{
    timestamps: true
});


const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
module.exports = Post;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was with post schema model where I have given reference as '**comment**' instead of '**Comment**'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you provided the server.js (or any starting point in your app) and as such, I am not sure if my example will provide any guidance, but I was able to get the controller to provide data to the view.  Here is my controller...

**./controllers/home.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const posts = require('../models/post');


router.get('/', (req, res, err) => {
    posts.find().populate("comments").exec().then(results => {
        console.log(results);
        return res.render('pages/home', { posts: results });
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

... and here is my view...

**./views/pages/home.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <%- include('../partials/head'); %>
</head>
<body class="container">

<header>
  <%- include('../partials/header'); %>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>testing</h1>

     <% for (post of posts){ %>
          <li><%= post._id %></li>
          <ul>
              <% for (comments of post.comments) { %>
                  <li><%= comments.content %></li>
              
              <% } %>
          </ul>
     <% }%>

     </ul>
  </div>
</main>

<footer>
  <%- include('../partials/footer'); %>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

... and here is the page rendered...

[image: Web Page Screen Shot]

Here are my documents in two collections...

- Posts
- Comments

**Posts**

```
Enterprise replSet [primary] nodetest> db.Posts.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61241efd7a37aa7000116773"),
    comments: [
      ObjectId("61241efd7a37aa7000116770"),
      ObjectId("61241efd7a37aa7000116771"),
      ObjectId("61241efd7a37aa7000116772")
    ],
    content: 'my post content',
    createdAt: ISODate("2021-08-23T22:19:41.193Z"),
    updatedAt: ISODate("2021-08-23T22:19:41.193Z"),
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61241f892b030d704c728176"),
    comments: [
      ObjectId("61241f892b030d704c728173"),
      ObjectId("61241f892b030d704c728174"),
      ObjectId("61241f892b030d704c728175")
    ],
    content: 'my post content',
    createdAt: ISODate("2021-08-23T22:22:01.949Z"),
    updatedAt: ISODate("2021-08-23T22:22:01.949Z"),
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

**Comments**

```
Enterprise replSet [primary] nodetest> db.Comments.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61241efd7a37aa7000116770"),
    content: 'Some loopy content 0',
    createdAt: ISODate("2021-08-23T22:19:41.193Z"),
    updatedAt: ISODate("2021-08-23T22:19:41.193Z"),
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61241efd7a37aa7000116771"),
    content: 'Some loopy content 1',
    createdAt: ISODate("2021-08-23T22:19:41.193Z"),
    updatedAt: ISODate("2021-08-23T22:19:41.193Z"),
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61241efd7a37aa7000116772"),
    content: 'Some loopy content 2',
    createdAt: ISODate("2021-08-23T22:19:41.193Z"),
    updatedAt: ISODate("2021-08-23T22:19:41.193Z"),
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61241f892b030d704c728173"),
    content: 'Some loopy content 0',
    createdAt: ISODate("2021-08-23T22:22:01.948Z"),
    updatedAt: ISODate("2021-08-23T22:22:01.948Z"),
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61241f892b030d704c728174"),
    content: 'Some loopy content 1',
    createdAt: ISODate("2021-08-23T22:22:01.949Z"),
    updatedAt: ISODate("2021-08-23T22:22:01.949Z"),
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61241f892b030d704c728175"),
    content: 'Some loopy content 2',
    createdAt: ISODate("2021-08-23T22:22:01.949Z"),
    updatedAt: ISODate("2021-08-23T22:22:01.949Z"),
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

**General Comments:**

It seems you are trying to have bi-directional references between collections.  That is to say, you have a parent-child relationship.  This is a one-to-may arrangement.  One post can have many comments.  Please correct me if this is not the case.  The post documents have an array of ObjectIDs for all the related child comments.  The Comment document has the parent Post ObjectID as well.  So the relationships are defined twice, once from the parent perspective, and another from the child perspective.

You did not provide any sample data, so I cannot determine if data details a mis-aligned.

When looking at your controller, it does not look like you are rendering a view.  Please take a look at my controller example.  This is how data is passed between the controller and the view.  If the data has not been passed it will not be available, hence an error such as the one you encountered.

For people trying to help you, it would make things a lot easier if you provided a simplified version of your problem, and to include all filenames, paths, etc. along with sample data.

I hope my examples provide some help.  Again, more clarity from your part would help in providing even more focused help.

Comment: I have provided index.js (starting point for my app).